# How to verify outputs of line code in a python function

Tags: python, function, rpc, pyez

I have test a function below and how can I verify the output of specific line in the function below.

```
def data():
   dev = Device(host="1.1.1.1", user="test", password="test123", port=22, 
   normalize=True)
   dev.open()
   resp = dev.rpc.get_interface_information(extensive=True)
   dev.close()

   for x in resp.findall(xxxxxxxxx): 
      if aaa
      else:
```

without function data() i can just type print(resp) and print(x) to check an verify the output of rpc send command or for loop above. But when i add the command inside the function im not able to do the same..in the function there is also few other line code of for loop and other rpc send command that i need to verify the output..Thus..how can i check specific output of code line inside a python function below....i have tried add data() and return below but it doesn't return anything

```
def data():
   dev = Device(host="1.1.1.1", user="test", password="test123", port=22, 
   normalize=True)
   dev.open()
   resp = dev.rpc.get_interface_information(extensive=True)
   return resp
   dev.close()

   for x in resp.findall(xxxxxxxxx): 
      if aaa
      else:
   return x 
data()
```

This is because i need to ensure the line code used in the function is correct and the output is verify ok. Please help and show me the correct way of doing it. Thank you.

Got error NameError: name 'request' is not defined

```
def data(request):
   dev = Device(host="1.1.1.1", user="test", password="test123", port=22, 
   normalize=True)
   dev.open()
   resp = dev.rpc.get_interface_information(extensive=True)
   print(resp)
   dev.close()

   for x in resp.findall(xxxxxxxxx): 
      if aaa
      else:
   return resp 
data(request)
```

Comment: `data()` does not return anything because you did not include a `return`statement in your function. For comparing strings, floats and integers, use `==`. For comparing instances or types of a python object, look up ìsinstance() `and `type()`.
However it is not clear to me what part you want to compare. Please make sure your code is reproducable for other users.

Comment: Hi sir..thank you....Im send command via rpc and this command line provide an details as a resp and i do search using findall in resp in for loop. i have include return resp before line dev.close() and test...no output generated... on my terminal...

Comment: Just `print(resp)` in the function - instead of the return

Comment: It doesn't work sir... normally outside function...i just use print() but when in function it doesn't work like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print statement should work inside a function. I am guessing you are putting print statement after return. In the code you have provided nothing after the return statement is going to be executed since the return statement will exit out of the function. Make sure you put return at the end when you are done with all the tasks you want your function to perform.

Also, you can only have one return statement in a function. If you want to return multiple variables put them in a list or use something like

```
return a, b
```

and then catch them like this

```
val_a, val_b = data()
```

Comment: Hi sir...If the function have parameter def data(req)?

Comment: That wouldn't change the return statement. You will only need to change how you call the function. `val_a, val_b = data(req)` where req is whatever you want to pass as parameter.

Comment: i test it with return resp, print(resp) and data() - Ok can generate print the output but when i test return resp, print(resp) and data(req) - error NameError: name 'req' is not defined... do u know what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you defined req before? req is supposed to be a variable when you are calling the data function

Comment: Its a views.py file of django .. sorry its a typo....it should be def data(request):

Comment: If that's the case, then this function will be called by html. Why are you calling it explicitly in the code?

Comment: U r right sir....from html called ok... actually Im trying to get the raw output for my own understanding and perhaps I could save the output (called by html) to text file also.... can I have it called explicitly in the code... I appreciate your help sir.

Comment: You'll have to write your own request object for you to be able to do this and then pass it as parameter. Maybe try printing out request when making call through html and then copy and paste that into your req parameter?

Comment: This is the function from html called  def index(request):
        resp = loader.get_template('test/index.html').render()
        return HttpResponse(resp)

Comment: That's the function defined in views.py. It is being called in an html form somewhere and the parameters are passed during call

Comment: Is it possible to get the output of resp from this function def index(request)? Because i think thats the output call by the html.

Comment: yes you can output resp from any function. Just add a print statement and make sure it is before return statement.

Comment: I test like this below def index(request): 
  resp = loader.get_template('test/index.html').render() 
  return HttpResponse(resp)
  print(resp)
  return resp
index(request)   and it return error File "views.py", line 71, in <module>
    index(request)
NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Comment: I'm guessing you are calling index on line 71 and passing "request" as a parameter. You have not defined request anywhere so it will throw error. You can't test like this. Find out what your request parameter actually is and copy paste that as parameter

Comment: Thank you sir...Im still getting the same error... i think 'request' is from django template...